# Why are rows where the value of the indexed column is not null, not showing in select statement?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So, I have this MySQL table that I have created with PHPMyAdmin. I am actually writing an app with PHP (Codeigniter) and MySQL that let the user look at SQL tables, add values or remove rows, add filters,...
Problem is, This particular SQL table has a foreign key, and so the column was automatically indexed. When I do a "SELECT *" query, I am able to get and print my entire table on my web page. But when I try to select only the primary keys column, the rows where there are values in the indexed column aren't showing. As an exemple, if the first and second rows have values in the indexed column, the first row showed as a result of the "SELECT id" statement would be the third one in the table.

I thought this was a problem with my code at first, but it seems this behaviour is reproducible within phpmyadmin when trying this same SQL query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table;
```

gives

```
| id | col1  | col2  | indexed_col |
| 1  | value | value | value       |
| 2  | value | value | value       |
| 3  | value | value | null        |
| 4  | value | value | null        |
```

and so on. But this :

```sql
SELECT id FROM table;
```

gives

```
| id |  
| 3  | 
| 4  |
```

I do not really understand this behaviour. I may have missed something, but if someone is able to explain why it works like that, or find a solution, i would be delighted.

**UPDATE**

My SQL table was probably broken, No idea why, I just recreated one. Issue solved

Comment: using same user for both? or different?

Comment: Does it happen in the `mysql` command line client?

Comment: Try repairing the table's indexes.

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde Using the same user for both, yes

Comment: @Barmar I'll look into it

Comment: @Barmar repairing the indexes does nothing. Funny thing is, when selecting any number of column with the id, it gives the right result. It happens ONLY when selecting id only

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pYTAJk4UgJTbVSzZnTyAdR/0

Comment: @Barmar I tried aswell, I see that the order is not 1,2,3,4 but 3,4,1,2. So, it would seems the "index not null" rows are at the end of my table, and that I would just have to do an order by on the id ?

Comment: Tables don't have any inherent order; if you care about the order of the results, you have to use `ORDER BY`. Otherwise they can be in any order.